# Can I make someone supply a reason for cancelling a recurring payment?

Tags: paypal

Is it possible to ask a person with a monthly subscription to supply the reason for cancelling when they cancel the subscription?

Comment: As a user, would you want to be _required_ to give someone a reason you're canceling a subscription with them? Do you think the majority of responses would be helpful?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on webmasters.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation I have viewed on PayPal Payments Standard Subscriptions, there is no way to make a buyer specify the reason for cancelling the subscription.
 
**Page 33** of the below **PayPal Subscription and Recurring Payment Guide** has all of the information on cancelling subscriptions.
[PayPal Subscription and Recurring Payments Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/archive/PP_subscriptions.pdf)

This information is based on the Standard PayPal Subscription Button, and not on using a third party shopping cart with Recurring Payments.